# Avoid going reverse

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Turtlebot3 (on the carpeted floor of my lab) doesn't do well going backwards. There must be a setting somewhere to avoid going backwards if possible? I assume this would be the planner not laying out a route which requires going in reverse. I suppose sometimes it is unavoidable, so this would be a "avoid reverse if possible". Is there something like that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298883/avoid-going-reverse/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not very familiar with the Turtlebot3, but I imagine if you're using one of their demo navigation setups you'll need to change the parameters for the local planner in one of the param files [here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/tree/master/turtlebot3_navigation/param). The parameter name you're looking for will depend on which local planner is used, but it should be something like "min_vel_x".

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1